# parent component is not getting data from child in Nuxt app

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, v-for, netlify-cms

This is driving me crazy so I hope that anyone can help.

I made a Nuxt app with @nuxt/content and I'm using Netlify-CMS to create content. That all seems to work fine. However I'm trying to display a component that contains a loop of the MD-files that I have, but in the index.vue nothing of the loop is displayed.

I know (a little) about props and $emit, but as I am not triggering an event this dosen't seem to work.

Component code:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <h1>Releases</h1>
    <li v-for="release of rfhreleases" :key="release.slug">
      <h2>{{ release.artist }}</h2>
    </li>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
    const rfhreleases = await $content('releases', params.slug)
      .only(['artist'])
      .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .fetch()

    return {
      rfhreleases,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

And index.vue code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Hero />
    <Releases />
    <About />
    <Contact />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      script: [
        { src: 'https://identity.netlify.com/v1/netlify-identity-widget.js' },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

If I place my component code as part of index.vue, everything work, but I would love to avoid that and thats why I'm trying to place the loop in a component.

Answer (score 1):

As stated on the Nuxt documentation:

> This hook can only be placed on page components.

That means `asyncData` only works on components under `pages/` folder.

You have several options:

1. You use `fetch` instead. It's the other asynchronous hook but it's called from any component. It won't block the rendering as with `asyncData` so the component it will instanciated with empty data first.
2. You fetch your data from the page with `asyncData` and you pass the result as a prop to your component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Hero />
    <Releases :releases="rfhreleases" />
    <About />
    <Contact />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
    const rfhreleases = await $content('releases', params.slug)
      .only(['artist'])
      .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .fetch()

    return {
      rfhreleases,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```